# Does scikit-learn have Bayes Net ? If yes is there an implementation for reference

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bayesian-networks

I need to classify the data using BayesNet in Python. I have used scikit learn for other classifiers like Random Forests, SVM etc. I know it has Naive Bayes but I am looking for Bayesian Network alone. If anyone could help me with it it would be very helpful Also, if there is an implementation of it for reference that would be even more helpful.
Thanks

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Weka for classify the data using BayesNet in Python.You can train your data using Weka and save your model as XML then you can write prediction API's in python for that saved model.